# Add additional security questions to SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

The default asp membership provider only allows for one security question and answer.  Does anyone know a work around to allow for more than one question and answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll you own MembershipProvider, probably SQL-based as well, inheriting from built-in and adding your own logic.

Comment: I was afraid that I'd have to expend the membership provider.  Thanks.

Comment: @Icono: That's pretty interesting :) Feel free to ask on SO